# Can't run protractor tests with selenium hub 4

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-grid

I am trying to run my protractor tests using a selenium hub. I follow the official selenium hub instructions to run it using docker. Basically the commands are as follows:

[image]

After that, I change the "seleniumAddress" in my conf.js as follow

[image]

When I run my test I get a timeout. It seems the session can't be created. This is the error:

```
Host info: host: '61320427d5f1', ip: '172.18.0.2'
Build info: version: '4.9.1', revision: 'eb2032df7f'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.49-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.18'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:514:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:519:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
```

Anyone can help me to resolve this issue? Any idea what happen?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you find a solution to running Protractor tests against Hub4?